# Making a rectangle border around text in Textbox python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, textbox, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-text

I want to have a rectangle border around certain text that is added to the text box from the end and will be placed at the center.

For example:

[image]

Unfortunately, I can't find a way to do that, because I
don't know how to place texts at the center of the line in the text box, and don't know how to surround a text with a rectangle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap a `Label` with border between a space and newline with `justify='center'` in a `Text` widget.

Below is an example:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

textbox = tk.Text(root, width=30, height=10)
textbox.pack()

textbox.tag_config('center', justify='center')

def center_label(textbox, **kwargs):
    textbox.insert('end', ' ', 'center')
    lbl = tk.Label(textbox, bd=3, relief='solid', **kwargs)
    textbox.window_create('end', window=lbl)
    textbox.insert('end', '\n\n')

center_label(textbox, text='hello', width=10, font='Arial 12 bold')
center_label(textbox, text='............', width=20)

textbox.insert('end', '\nhello\n')

root.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: wow! looks good!!! how can I add a bg color to the frame?

Comment: Do you mean the color of the border?

Comment: No, I mean the inside of the frame.

Comment: Add `bg=...` to `center_label(...)`.

Comment: Last thing, how can I make the width of the label change according to an inputted text I want to insert into the text box?

Comment: because I want it to fit exactly the length of the text I am inserting.

Comment: Don't specify the `width` option.

Comment: Right! don't know how I didn't think about that. Thanks so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the text box into it's own frame.

Some thing like this:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()

labelframe = LabelFrame(root, text="LabelFrame")
labelframe.pack()

text = Label(labelframe, text="Text inside labelframe")
text.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I still can't understand how to add the text with a rectangle to the text box.

Comment: The frame willact as a rectangle surrounding the text

Comment: Can you please show me how you do it with the Text box? because I really cannot see how to do it from what you wrote.

Comment: The code I supplied tell you how to creat a frame and how to put their inside of it. If you would like you can read this article on frames. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_frame.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can add the border to the Entry using `relief = "solid"`, centre the text with `outline` and you can use `grid` to align the widgets the way you want.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x200")
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

ent1 = tk.Entry(root, relief = "solid", justify = "center")
ent1.insert(0, "hello")
ent1.grid(row = 0, column = 0, pady = 10)

ent2 = tk.Entry(root, relief = "solid", justify = "center")
ent2.insert(0, ".......")
ent2.grid(row = 1, column = 0, pady = 10)

lab1 = tk.Label(root, text = "hello")
lab1.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = "w")

lab2 = tk.Label(root, text = "hello")
lab2.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = "w")

root.mainloop()
```

Most of this is straightforward, the `root.grid_columnconfigure` line makes the grid take up the full width of the root window by giving the first column a weight of 1. The result is very similar to your example:
[image: Image of Tkinter window]

Comment: But the whole point is to combine it with the text box's texts

Comment: maybe is there a way to add a tag configuration to the text box, so that the text will be surrounded by a rectangle?

Comment: What do you mean by a text box? An Entry or a Label? If you just want to put everything in a Frame (a box) with a border that's possible.

Comment: neither of them, I mean Text, is a block of text that can add text to it.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_text.htm see this...
I was able to insert the text at the center with JUSTIFY and a tag_configure, but 
cannot insert a rectangle around the text I am inserting. 
If it isn't clear in the post I can add to it.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an `Entry` widget in the textbox using `text.window_create()`. You could customize the border of the `Entry` widget, and you would be able to type text inside it. To make it look more like part of the textbox, you should register events so when the user presses <kbd>Right</kbd> and the caret is one character left of the `Entry`, give the `Entry` focus using `focus_set`. You could do the same with the <kbd>Left</kbd>.